# Некорректное функционирование overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, html5, scss

Хочу сделать кнопку с плавным заполнением заполнением `background` внутри при наведении курсора, но возникла проблема с непонятным белым местом при применении `overflow: hidden;`

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы убрать этот пробел?

Картинка

[image: Картинка с пробелом]

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 12px 55px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #2869CA;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #2869ca;
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 19px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #2869CA, #2881CF);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
        Read more
    </button>
```

Comment: Чего-то  не наблюдаю тут проблемы

Comment: Всмысле все нормально работает?

Comment: тут в примере да, все нормально работает

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел в firefox, там проблемы нет, а вот в google chrome есть

Comment: Я с оперы, тот же хром... и даже в хроме глянул, нет у меня ничего такого, что описано в вопросе

Comment: Я сейчас заметил, что когда меняю zoom в браузере проблема то появляется, то пропадает. Это с чем может быть связано?

Comment: а зум то на кой трогать?  оставь его в покое выстави на 100% и все, работай

Comment: @Air, у меня отображается сомнительно, хотя и не так, как у ватора на скрине.

Comment: на 100 проблема у меня видна, а при 90 нет)))

Comment: @Александр, добавь анимацию в вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ее пока нет

Comment: @Александр, тогда просто переделывай.

Comment: @Qwertiy, у него же там градиент, а он еще и с масштабирование играет, искажение будет по любому...  Это же вечная проблема градиента

Comment: @Air, поэтому я и просил добавить в вопрос анимацию, чтобы можно было сделать сразу с ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

border, border-radius и overflow: hidden вместе работают плохо. На разных браузерах и устройствах могут возникать траблы.

```
.button {
      position: relative;
      margin: 20px;
      padding: 12px 55px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border: 1px solid #2869CA;
      border-radius: 50px;
      color: #2869ca;
      font-family: 'Nunito';
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 19px;
      outline: none;
      z-index: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
      &:hover{
        color: #fff;
        &:before{
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }
```

Убрал overflow: hidden;
У псевдоэлемента сделал такой же радиус как и у родительского элемента дабы небыло коллизий.
Ширина и высота +2px за счет border'а (верх, низ) (лево, право) по 1px c каждой стороны.
+ Отрицательный маргин -1px с каждой стороны, чтобы выйти за рамки родительского элемента.
Задал псевдоэлементу z-index: -1, чтобы он не перекрывал текст кнопки
И анимируем все это дело с помощью opacity

```
.button:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      width: calc(100% + 2px);
      height: calc(100% + 2px);
      border-radius: 50px;
      margin: -1px;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      transition: all .5s ease;
      border: 1px solid #2869CA;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #2869CA, #2881CF);
    }
```

Comment: Ну и о чем сей ответ? Интересно как он решает проблему описанную в вопросе?

Comment: Это ответ о том, что не нужно задавать border-radius и overflow: hidden у разных элементов. Они плохо вместе работают. И да, еще и border. К тому, же он не сможет анимировать background transition'ном потому, что он использует градиент. С отрицательным маргином на всех устройствах все будет в порядке.

Comment: Нууу, и где комментарии и пояснения к ответу...  Оформи ответ нормально, поясни...

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ и пояснения. У меня проблема решилась очень странно: я случайно поменял padding по горизонтали на 56px и оно заработало так, как надо. Честно говоря, я сам полностью не разобрался из-за чего у меня возникает это искажение и почему это происходит только на нечетных padding. На четных все работает нормально)))